# Modifying settings.json in vscode to add shell escape flag to pdflatex in latex workshop

Tags: json, visual-studio-code, latex, pdflatex

I'm new to VSCode and I am setting up LaTeX. I am trying to compile a .tex document that uses minted and thus pdflatex needs the --shell-escape flag. I am trying to modify the settings.json to do this.

I have tried adding the following (found on the internet)

```
 {
    "latex-workshop.latex.tools": {
        "name": "pdflatex",
        "command": "pdflatex",
        "args": [
            "--shell-escape", 
            "-synctex=1",
            "-interaction=nonstopmode",
            "-file-line-error",
            "%DOC%"
        ]
    }
}
```

However it comes up with an error:
Incorrect type. Expected "array".
This wont even let me try to build with latex workshop. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: which tex distribution do you have? texlive or miktex?

Comment: You probably already know that, but the listings package does a job equivalent to minted and works out-of-the-box, without any external program.  [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/389191/minted-vs-listings-pros-and-cons) is a discussion on their compared merits.

Comment: Texlive distribution. I don't want to use listings.

Comment: If it is not obvious how to add --shell-escape to pdflatex, perhaps it is just better to compile using the command line interface in vscode? I am only modifying some small details of a paper and so it wont bother me if it is not the optimal way to do it.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem and after looking like crazy on the internet I found the solution.
The snippet that you have there is wrongly formatted that's why is complaining.
And is only for the pdf latex recipe.
Here is the snippet that needs to be added to `settings.json`.

```
{
  ...,

  "latex-workshop.latex.tools": [
      {
        "name": "latexmk",
        "command": "latexmk",
        "args": [
          "-synctex=1",
          "-interaction=nonstopmode",
          "-file-line-error",
          "--shell-escape",
          "-pdf",
          "%DOC%"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "pdflatex",
        "command": "pdflatex",
        "args": [
          "--shell-escape",
          "-synctex=1",
          "-interaction=nonstopmode",
          "-file-line-error",
          "%DOC%"
        ]
      },
      {
        "name": "bibtex",
        "command": "bibtex",
        "args": [
          "%DOCFILE%"
        ],
        "env": {}
      }
    ],

  ...
}
```

I found the solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432459/pygmentize-not-installed-error-on-visual-studio-code) in a question related to the pygmentize package